cant install php 8.2 to mac os Big Sur(11) with homebrew
I cant install php 8.2 with BREW on my Imac with mac os 11 (Big Sur).
When I write BREW INSTALL php@8.2 in the terminal, it downloads the dependencies, starts installing them and ......
==> Fetching openexr
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/651ab1c
Already downloaded: /Users/dmitrij/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/fbe1f966b03328ee5324e472eb2169424788a9688a45e5c07d93144adfb380af--openexr.rb
==> Downloading https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openexr-images/raw/
Already downloaded: /Users/dmitrij/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ba0da2a31c9ecfc80347695d4b2135fbec9f60358d1029a5402cfffb64a38ebf--AllHalfValues.exr
==> Downloading https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openexr/archive/ref
Already downloaded: /Users/dmitrij/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/5c1b6fb3948c7430a5ed5806a0c7de2d4b01cec4546cb212611e6842e61e7eca--openexr-3.2.4.tar.gz
==> cmake ..
Last 15 lines from /Users/dmitrij/Library/Logs/Homebrew/openexr/01.cmake:
-- Using Imath from /usr/local/lib/cmake/Imath
-- Performing Test OPENEXR_IMF_HAVE_SYSCONF_NPROCESSORS_ONLN
-- Performing Test OPENEXR_IMF_HAVE_SYSCONF_NPROCESSORS_ONLN - Success
-- Performing Test OPENEXR_IMF_HAVE_GCC_INLINE_ASM_AVX
-- Performing Test OPENEXR_IMF_HAVE_GCC_INLINE_ASM_AVX - Success
-- Looking for include file ucontext.h
-- Looking for include file ucontext.h - not found
-- OpenEXR pkg-config generation enabled
-- Configure OpenEXR 3.2.4, library API version: 31.3.2.4
-- Building OpenEXR libraries
-- Building OpenEXR tools
-- Building OpenEXR examples
-- clang-format not found.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core!
Error: You are using macOS 11.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.
Do not report this issue: you are running in an unsupported configuration.
I reinstall brew, tried it update/upgrage brew, update-reset, nothing helps.
How can i fix it? How can i install php 8.2 to another way?

You could use macports for OS11. First you will need to install macports https://www.macports.org/install.php#installing then follow the instructions for php8.2 at https://ports.macports.org/port/php82/

Similar problem here. I finally found the issue with
brew install --verbose openexr

It showed somewhere that "libdeflate" was not found, so I installed it manually with:
brew install libdeflate

Now I could install "openexr" and php normally.

This solved my problem on Catalina (10.15.7)
